# Is there a solution to redirect a page with a select option from the database that i added with a input field?

Tags: php, database, forms

I am trying to create a option list , using a input field. The input field submits the data to my databse and in the same time i create a new file with the name of the value that i added in the input field and attach a exetension of ".php" to create a php file. Also together with the value i send also the file path into the database. In the index.php you can see the following code:
**INDEX.PHP**

```
    <?php
include "conn.php";
$query="SELECT DISTINCTname,filePath FROM name_data";
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<select name="select_list" id="list" onchange="location=this.value">

<?php foreach($res as $name){?>

    <option value="<?php echo $name['filePath'];?>"><?php echo $name['name'] ;?></option>

<?php };?>


</select><br><br>
<form action="set.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"><br><br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And for the form submission i use the following code. Now in this example i dont use RegEx for the input field its just a simple code that i am trying:
**SET.PHP**

```
    <?php
include "conn.php";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $name=$_POST['name'];

     $path=$name.".php";


     $query="INSERT INTO name_data(name,filePath) VALUES('$name','$path')";
     if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)){

         header("LOCATION:index.php");
     }
      fopen($path,"w");
};
```

Now What i want to do, when i query the database i want the value(name) from the form submission to be linked to the corresponding file path(file Path) that i created during form submission.

Comment: You cannot echo and use a header at the same time.

Comment: yes that was my mistake ,,, from testing the code i correct that

Comment: What what I gather, you'd need to query the database using SELECT and then adding an [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) to it.

Comment: Please clarify your question with example, it's unclear. If `$path="something"` you want to redirect to `something.php`?

Comment: i am submiting a form to the database with the value exmp:"name". Now from that value that send to database is the value "name" and a file that i created using the value as in this case "name.php". Also during the form submition i am creating the file with fopen(name.".php");. Then when i query the database i echo the value of the path from the databse to the value of the option , and the value iself as  text of the option.i want to be able to match the path from the databse with the value of the option list so every time i change the value of the option list, i can navigate to the page i need